# Generating a non-polymorphic query using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722780/how-to-avoid-polymorphic-behaviour-in-entity-framework-tpt-inheritance-in-order?rq=1), except I am using *Entity Framework 6.2.*

I am using [Inheritance with EF Code First: Table per Type (TPT)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt).

I have a parent class called BasicAd:

```
[Table("basicad")]
public class BasicAd
{
    public long BasicAdId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    // more properties
}
```

And I have a child class called: RealEstateRental:

```
[Table("realestaterental")]
public class RealEstateRental : BasicAd
{
    [Required]
    public short NoOfBedrooms { get; set; }

    // more properties
}
```

I let entity framework to create my DB tables from the above classes, which is done as expected. It creates *BasicAd* table and *RealEstateRental* table (DB is MySQL).

This is my ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyDB")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<BasicAd> BasicAd { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext>());
    }
}
```

Now I want to use a [Non-polymorphic Query](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph), to select from BasicAd (only *BasicAd*, I don't want any join to *RealEstateRental*):

public BasicAd GetBasicAd(long id)
        {

```
        var query = from b in Context.BasicAd.OfType<BasicAd>() where b.BasicAdId == id select b;
        return query.SingleOrDefault();

        // I have tried this too: 
        // return Context.BasicAd
        //               .OfType<BasicAd>()
        //               .AsNoTracking()
        //               .FirstOrDefault(r => r.BasicAdId == id);
```

But when I check the query that is generated by EF, I see it is a polymorphic query, I, i.e. it is including *RealEstateRental* in the join:

[image]

How can I only query on *basicad* table?

Comment: `OfType` means `is`, and `RealEstateRental` *is a* `BasicAd`. I'm afraid there is no EF compatible construct to query only for `BasicAd`.

Comment: @IvanStoev: thanks. So adding OfType is making no difference to the above query? Do I need to write my own stored procedure to achieve the above?

Comment: I think so. If you look closely at the non-polymorphic query example from the link, the base entity is *abstract*, and `OfType` is used to retrieve concrete *derived* type. While you are using non abstract base type. I'm unsure what is your goal. If you want to query `BasicAd` which is not `RealEstateRental`, you could try `Context.BasicAd.Where(ba => !(ba is RealEstateRental))`.

Comment: @IvanStoev: Thanks a lot. I am making an e-commerce website. I have a BasicAd  (parent )and lots of specialized (child) Ads, e.g. CarAd, RealEstateRentalAd, JobAd, etc. While reading the data, I know the type of the Ad, so I want to read Data from the correct table, instead of joining / union all of the above types.

Comment: You could model BasicAd as a sibling of RealEstateRental, instead of its base class.  BasicAd is really doing double duty here.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: Thanks a lot. So I can make BasicAd an abstract Base Class and inherit my concrete classes from it. Let's say I would have SimpleAd & CarAd as children of BasicAd (what you suggested). Would this solve my problem above with non-polymorphic query?

Comment: Probably worth testing :)